# How to customize jquery mobile datebox customflipbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, customization, datebox

I am working in [jquerymobile datebox customflip, plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/mode/customflipbox.html). i am having problem in 3 things. first in title, how can i change title 'undefined' second how can i change button text 'Looks Good'. Third how can i show text on input instead of index

heres [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/rU4S9/)

code

```
 <h2>Custom Box Mode</h2>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
                        'customData': [  {
                            'input': true,
                            'name': '',
                            'data': ['Single', 'Separated', 'Involved', 'Married','Widowed','Lover','Other']
                        }],
                        'useNewStyle': false,
                        'overrideStyleClass': 'ui-icon-dice'
                    });
                    </script>
                    <style>
                    .ui-icon-dice {
                        background-image: url('http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/img/dice.png') !important;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: 99% 50%;
                    }
                    </style>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="cf">Custom</label>
                        <input name="cf" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="cf" data-options='{"mode": "customflip"}' />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button text is modified by the `overrideCustomSet` property.

```
var selectdata = ['Single', 'Separated', 'Involved', 'Married', 'Widowed', 'Lover', 'Other'];

jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
    "customData": [{ "input": true, "name": "", "data": selectdata }],
     "customDefault": [0],
     "useNewStyle": true,
     "enablePopup": false,
     "centerHoriz": true,
     "centerVert": true,
     "useFocus": true,
     "useButton": false,
     "useHeader": true,
     "overrideCustomSet": "Looks Good",
     "overrideCustomFormat": "%%"   
});
```

For the other 2 problems you could handle the `datebox` event. When the event method is `postrefresh`, set the dialog title, and when the method is `set`, find the text by index from the array and make it the value of the input.

```
$('#cf').on('datebox', function (e, p) {
    if (p.method === 'postrefresh') {
        $(".ui-datebox-container h1.ui-title").html("My Title");
    }
    if (p.method === 'set') {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        $(this).val(selectdata[p.value]);
    }
});
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rU4S9/9/)**

Comment: First, wow, didn't know anybody was actually using this.  cool.  And I'm impressed, you seem to know it better than I do.

Comment: Second, I'll add an option to override header - right now it's either the label text, or the placeholder attribute. I'll make it hardcodeable.

Comment: Finally, your second function is not needed.  customFormat is not i18n aware, so you can: "customFormat": "%Xa"  (%X1... = numeric index, %Xa... = text of option)

Comment: @J.T.Sage, Thank you for developing jQM plugins! I like it that you provide plenty of flexibility and good documentation. Also, thanks for the comments and suggestions on this question, you are welcome to update my jsFiddle if you like.

Comment: Here you go - with the changed format, and with a new option "customHead" - http://jsfiddle.net/rU4S9/18/

Comment: @J.T.Sage, did you update the references in the fiddle or at your cdn, because the title for me just says "custom" and not "Some Title!"

Comment: I thought I did.  cache?  (it looks like it's linked to /latest/, which did get pushed to)